# Cluster similar - but not identical - digits in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe with 2M+ rows. One of the columns `pin`, contains a series of 14 digits.

I'm trying to cluster similar — but not identical — digits. Specifically, I want to match the first 10 digits without regard to the final four. The `pin` column was imported as an `int` then converted to a `string`.

Put another way, the first 10 digits should match but the final four shouldn't. Duplicates of exact-matching pins should be dropped.

For example these should all be grouped together:

```
17101110141403
17101110141892
17101110141763
17101110141199
17101110141788
17101110141851
17101110141831
17101110141487
17101110141914
17101110141843
```

Desired output:

```
Biggest cluster | other columns
Second biggest cluster | other columns
...and so on | other columns
```

I've tried using a combination of `groupby` and `regex` without success.

```
pat2 = '1710111014\d\d\d\d'
pat = '\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d'

grouped = df2.groupby(df2['pin'].str.extract(pat, expand=False), axis= 1)
```

and

```
df.groupby(['pin']).filter(lambda group: re.match > 1)
```

Here's a link to the original data set: https://datacatalog.cookcountyil.gov/Property-Taxation/Assessor-Parcel-Sales/wvhk-k5uv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear why you need regex for this, what about the following(assuming pin is stored as a string) (Note that you haven't included your expected output)

```
    pin
0   17101110141403
1   17101110141892
2   17101110141763
3   17101110141199
4   17101110141788
5   17101110141851
6   17101110141831
7   17101110141487
8   17101110141914
9   17101110141843

df.groupby(df['pin'].str[:10]).size()

pin
1710111014    10
dtype: int64
```

If you want this information appended back to your original dataframe, you can use

```
df['size']=df.groupby(df['pin'].astype(str).str[:10])['pin'].transform(len)

    pin size
0   17101110141403  10
1   17101110141892  10
2   17101110141763  10
3   17101110141199  10
4   17101110141788  10
5   17101110141851  10
6   17101110141831  10
7   17101110141487  10
8   17101110141914  10
9   17101110141843  10
```

Then, assuming you have more columns, you can sort your dataframe by size of cluster with

```
df.sort_values('size')
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to frame my expected output since there are an unknown number of desired clusters in the data, other than 'cluster 1, cluster 2, etc...' The catch is that I don't know what the proceeding 10 digits are that I want to group by - that's what I'm trying to find.

Comment: The code in my answer will group by the first 10 digits regardless of what they are, is the edited code close to what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: It is close. Will it avoid counting duplicated pin entries? Avoiding duplication is desired. (I tried specifying that in my question where I said that the first 10 digits should match, but the final four shouldn't. Which in hindsight may have been a poor way to word that).

Comment: No, this will count the entries regardless of the last 4. It's not clear how you want that behavior handled: Would a recommendation to `drop_duplicates()` first suffice, or if there are identical pin entries should they somehow by grouped differently? Might be worth editing your original question

Comment: For example, if you run `df.groupby(df['pin'].drop_duplicates().astype(str).str[:10])['pin'].transform(len)` then the duplicate entries will still exist, but will be `NaN` in the size column

Comment: Starting with `drop_duplicates()` on the `pin` column should suffice. (If I recall, `drop_duplicates()` keeps the first entry but removes all repeated ones? I edited my question for more clarity.

Comment: That's controlled by the parameter `keep{‘first’, ‘last’, False}, default ‘first’`. See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)